# Update user's page in the same way Facebook do

Tags: httprequest

I am developing a web app for a little company. There, for example, we can have users A,B and C that are from a account team. We can have a users D,F,G,H that are form sales team.
Each user has his own private page, like Facebook and they are linked by team, that means in Facebook language, A is friend from B an C, not from D,F,G,H. So when B sends a new thought for the team the others team users (A,C) can see the message.
So my question is, lets say the user A is logged in at his page and user B send a message to the team, how to update the user A and C browser in the same way we see in facebook when we have new posts from our friends?
For the moment I could think about a script, trough AJAX, that could check in the database for the new posts from "myFriends" each 5seconds. But I dont think Facebook do this. Maybe Facebook use HTTP persistent conections http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection . I dont know.
In fact I dont know the best way (best practices) to achieve this results. Idont know even the tags I should use for this question.
Any thought? 
Update: I am using php, AJAX, Bootsrap jQuery, MySQL

Comment: What technologies are you using? NodeJS / asp.net??
Provide more info please

Comment: Sorry I will update that. Iam using php, AJAX, Bootsrap jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estimated.
Whereas want similar functionality to Facebook, if you check the console (with Firebug in my case) you realize that always makes GET requests to the server, both for notifications to Chat. That is, do not use Http Persistent. You could use **$.ajax()** function of jQuery to make GET Requests, get a JSON and update the elements you want in your page.
[image]

Comment: Ok, so what is the trigger? Some kind of regular request? That means at each 3seconds as I thougth?

Comment: the trigger could be a setTimeout() function in JQuery. This function call other function (yourFunctionName) each XXXX miliseconds.